# Creating a queue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object, queue

I'm writing a queue in javascript, and am not sure what is the best way to implement it:

Option 1:

Do something like...

```
var queue = []
```

...and use push/shift functions to enqueue/dequeue.

Option 2:

Create an object like so:

```
var myQueue = new function() {
  this.queue = [];
  this.enqueue(x) = function() { this.queue.push(x) };
  this.dequeue() = function { this.queue.shift() };
}
```

Option 3:

Something else that you suggest?

The only advantage that I can see to using option 2 over 1 is that if I want to create a unique method to call on myQueue (e.g. dequeueTwoElements), I'd be able to do so.

Thoughts?

Comment: I've looked at Queue.js but don't want to use 3rd party libraries for now.

Comment: dequeue needs to return the result `return this.queue.shift();`.

Comment: Probably want the function to be a named function so you can reuse it more than once for more than one purpose.

Comment: @jfriend00 Will fix the return, thanks! I'm curious about where these functions could be reused? In another queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there IS a best way to implement it.  Wrapping your queue in a custom object will provide all the benefits of encapsulation, and implementation hiding.

Suppose for some reason you wanted to change `myQueue` to use an object instead of an array internally, it would allow you to do that, without messing up any of its clients.

Additionally, I think it will be easier for someone new to your code to explicitly understand that your queue is indeed a queue.  This is because they have a function constructor definition to look at, and the `enqueue` and `dequeue` function are more explicit then passing around an array named `queue` and calling js array methods on it.